# ActiveMQ non-persistent delivery mode limitations?

Tags: performance, jms, spring-integration, activemq-classic, consumer

I am using ActiveMQ where I need following requirements

- To have very fast consumers as my producers are already very fast
- Need processing at lease 2K messages per second
- Not require to process/consume messages again in case of server crash or other failures. I can trigger whole process again.
- Needs to run very normal configuration server - 4Gib RAM

I have configured ActiveMQ as given below

- Using `non-persistent delivery mode` (`vm://localhost`)(http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html)
- Using spring integration for put/fetch messages in/from queue/channel.
- Using `max-concurrent-consumers` with `10` threads
- Assume all other configs are by default with ActiveMQ and Sprig-integration.

**Problems/Questions**

- I am not sure how ActiveMQ stores messages in case of `non-persistent delivery mode`, is it possible that my process will fail with out of memory errors once my queue size exceed some limit? I am asking this because it's very difficult to test whole process for me. So I needs to be aware about limitation before I trigger the process.
- If `non-persistent delivery mode` is not sufficient with my above requirements, is there any performance tuning tips with which I can achieve my requirements with `persistent delivery mode` (`tcp://`). I have already tested with this mode, but it seems consumers are very slow here. Also, I have already tried to use `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` to make my consumer fast with `persistent delivery mode` but no luck.

NOTE : I am using latest ActiveMQ version `5.14`

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure how ActiveMQ stores messages in case of non-persistent delivery mode

Activemq store messages in the memory at first, and it will also swap it to the disk(there is a tmp_storage folder in activemq's data path).

> is it possible that my process will fail with out of memory errors once my queue size exceed some limit

I have never met out of memory in activemq, even with about one million messages.

You can also make sure by the producer flow control(http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html). 
You can make the producer hang when there is too many messages not consumed.

And about performance of persistent delivery, I also have no good methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @MallowFox.. can you explain bit about `producer-flow`. As per my understanding it's automatic configured right? or should we needs to do anything to slow producer flow in case of heavy load?

Comment: @Vishal Zanzrukia  You just need to set the memoryUsage limit and tempUsage limit in activemq's config xml. And the producer is automatically slowed down when there is heavy load.